# Is there a temporary fix for Jeep Grand Cherokee Dodge Durango power pump relay recall v62?

Tags: jeep, relay, fuel-pump, recall

FCA in November 2019 issued a second recall for 2011-2014 vehicles, but has still not devised a fix and all dealers will turn away customers seeking a fix because there is no direction from FCA and no parts made specifically for this issue.

I have a 2012 Grand Cherokee that is both listed by VIN for this recall and is exhibiting the issues associated with it. Without direction from dealers and FCA, I don't know what to do in the meantime.

---

To understand the issue, [a legal firm summarizes it well](https://thelemonfirm.com/2019/12/09/jeep-grand-cherokee-dodge-durango-stalling-concerns-the-hits-just-keep-on-coming/). In general, there is a non-removable power relay that manages the fuel pump. This part has been deemed a safety issue and it's recalled under recall ID v62. When faulting, the vehicle will not start and/or cause a stall while driving. I'm experiencing mostly a "no start" issue, though with the coming summer heat, I'm also experiencing stalls when it does start.

Comment: A “recall” means rhat you take it to the dealer for a specified repair. How can a recall be issued which does not have a repair.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This doesn't seem realistic, if an auto company issues a recall it means that there is *something* that needs to be done. This may mean a replacement part, inspection or risk mitigation action. Fiat isn't going to issue a recall without guidance or parts.

Comment: [In the recall](https://repairpal.com/recall/19V813000), it states: "*Vehicles that experience a fuel pump failure will receive an interim repair.*" This sounds as though there is a "fix" which can be done.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I'll call a few more dealers, but out of four I called, the one that will work on jeeps told me there's no parts. I suppose that could mean they don't have any, but they left me with the impression that there's *no parts being made*.

Comment: I recieved my recall notice in the mail last week. I did replace a relay twice that seemed to help. I'll report back with info on what they actually do.

Comment: I sold the car a few months later. Never had the relay officially fixed.

Comment: How spiteful people can be. [I give criticism on a post with a vocal downvote](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/94291/58368), then I magically I get a downvote on a question from years ago that has had no activity since it was first posted. You are a worthless, dishonest loser. And you might not recognize me, since I have a different name on every SE site, but I know you, and I'm not at all surprised to see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you guys had a previous recall done, then you already have an external fuel pump relay installed next to your fuse bob. These external relays started failing and just need to be replaced. You can use any good quality standard relay as temporary fix.

Comment: This is true, and it's the fix I've implemented a while ago, but forgot to self-answer here.

Answer (score -1):

I experienced stalling in My 2012 Jeep V6 this weekend. After driving for about 3 hours, I stopped at a parking lot and suddenly the engine sputters and shuts down. There was some squeaking noise that seemed like coming from the accessory belt. I started the car and it started up and shut down again. I checked the Engine temperature and it was fine. After waiting in the parking lot for about 30 minutes I started up the car and was able to drive home. The engine was rough at idle but runs fine otherwise. The neighborhood shop couldn’t find any OBD codes. Called two dealerships and they said they neither have the parts for the Recall nor a temporary fix. This is a serious safety issue. It’s unbelievable chrysler cannot offer a temporary fix.

Comment: The inconsistency in repeating the problem is very typical in *faulty relay* problems. I haven't called any other dealers as suggested above yet. I live close to work, so I walked today. Might not get to this until the weather goes bad again.